# How to drop a value from a list if it is not present in any other list

Tags: r, list

Say, for example, I have 5 lists named a, b, c, d, e. List a contains [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], list b contains [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], list c contains [2, 3, 5, 6, 7], list d contains [2, 4, 5], list e contains [3, 5, 7].

The data I am working with is much more complex, so I need to find a way to read each value from each list, check if it is present in any other lists, and if not, drop it from the original list. So when it reads list a, it sees that "1" is not present in any of the other lists, so "1" should be dropped from list a.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share some reproducible data and expected output

Comment: How do you recognize the element, by name?

Comment: Generally, you can use the `%in%` condition to test if a value is present in a vector of values. The output will be boolean, which you can use to drop `FALSE` cases. Short example: `sapply(b, function(x) x %in% c)` will output `TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# assuming you have a list of lists
a=list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);b=list(2, 3, 4, 5, 6);c=list(2, 3, 5, 6, 7);d=list(2,4,5);e=list(3,5,7)
my_list = list(a,b,c,d,e)

# first unlist each list
my_list = lapply(my_list,unlist)


n=length(my_list)
new_list = lapply(seq(n), function(x)
                   {my_list[[x]][my_list[[x]] %in% unlist(my_list[-x])]})
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 2 3 5 6 7

[[4]]
[1] 2 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 3 5 7
```

Comment: A little simpler, setting the function to `myList[[x]][myList[[x]] %in% unlist(myList[-x])]`.

Comment: Thanks, that's simpler indeed! Modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
c <- c(2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
d <- c(2, 4, 5)
e <- c(3, 5, 7)
```

Retain only the values that are in other vectors:

```
a[a %in% b | a %in% c | a %in% d | a %in% e]
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: What happens when there are hundreds of lists?

Comment: The post said specifically that there were 5 lists

Comment: 5 lists as an example... the post said, and I quote, "*Say, for example, I have 5 lists*". In addition, you should always be careful not to over-fit answers as your solutions are here to help more people that have the same problem. Another person might have the same problem with 1000 lists.

Comment: Right I see that now :) Maybe someone with exactly 5 lists will find my answer useful.